# Linq - how to sort dynamically by three expressions?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to order a result by a dynamic `expression` variable. If I change `DateTime`, `double?` and `int` to an `object` I get a `NotSupportedException`. I have the following three expressions

```
Expression<Func<Recipe, DateTime>> byCreatedOn = x => x.CreatedOn;
Expression<Func<Recipe, double?>> byRank = entity => entity.Comments.Any() ? entity.Comments.Average(comment => comment.Rating) : 0;
Expression<Func<Recipe, int>> byPopularity = x => x.Comments.Count();

var expression = order == 1 ? byRank : (order == 2 ? byPopularity : byCreatedOn);
```

and the following query

```
var list = this.DbContext.RecipeTranslations
            .Where(x => x.Language.Code == this.CurrentLanguge)
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || x.Title.Contains(name))
            .Select(x => x.Recipe)
            .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
            .Where(x => category == null || x.Categories.Any(cat => cat.Id == category))
            .OrderByDescending(expression)
            .Skip(start).Take(size).toList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to do is split out your query building, from materialization.

```
var query = this.DbContext.RecipeTranslations
            .Where(x => x.Language.Code == this.CurrentLanguge)
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || x.Title.Contains(name))
            .Select(x => x.Recipe)
            .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
            .Where(x => category == null || x.Categories.Any(cat => cat.Id == category));

if (order == 1)
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(byRank);
}
else if (order == 2)
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(byPopularity);
}
else
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(byCreatedOn);
}

// Finally
var list = query.Skip(start).Take(size).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your expressions evaluate you should be able to do:

```
.OrderByDescending(expression1).ThenBy(expression2)
```

and so on.

Comment: I am looking to sort only by one expression based on the variable order without using `ThenBy` and without writing 3 different queries in a switch or if.

Answer (score 0):

`int`, `double`, `DateTime` already implements `IComparable` interface.

Type of object (the one you use instead of `int`, `DateTime` or `double`) should also implement `IComparable` interface.

Or maybe you can try other overload of `OrderByDescending` method, which asks for a comparer.